# How to add a single axis label to multiple graphs

Tags: graphs

Please I need someone to help me address this problem.

I have three graphs that I created using excel and I have been able to save them as eps files. I've been able to use the `\raisebox` command to arrange the graphs in the order I want but adding the axis title has being a big problem for me. Please find attached a picture showing what I need to achieve. I have also included a working extract of my code.

[image: Task]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\newsubfloat{figure}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htb]
  \centering
  \raisebox{\dimexpr-.5\height-1em}{\includegraphics[scale=0.4]{Figures/knockho1.eps}}\ \subfloat[\label{label1}]{} \\[\topskip]
  \raisebox{\dimexpr-.5\height-1em}{\includegraphics[scale=0.4]{Figures/knockho2.eps}}\ \subfloat[\label{label2}]{}
  \caption{This is the text that describes \protect\subref{label1} and \protect\subref{label2}.}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

One way to do this would be to define a `minipage` to contain the y-axis, and simply place the text for the x-axis with an appropriate `\hspace*{}` preceding it.

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newsubfloat{figure}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htb]
\begin{minipage}{0.5cm}
\rotatebox{90}{\textcolor{red}{$y$-axis label}}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\linewidth-2.50cm\relax}%
  \raisebox{\dimexpr-.5\height-1em}{\includegraphics[scale=0.4]{Figures/knockho1.eps}}\ \subfloat[\label{label1}]{} \\[\topskip]
  \raisebox{\dimexpr-.5\height-1em}{\includegraphics[scale=0.4]{Figures/knockho2.eps}}\ \subfloat[\label{label2}]{}
  
  \vspace*{0.1cm}\hspace*{2.0cm}\textcolor{red}{$x$-axis label}
  \caption{This is the text that describes \protect\subref{label1} and \protect\subref{label2}.}
\end{minipage}%
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks so much Peter. You answer was nice except that the labels (a) and (b) are now below the figures instead of staying at the sides of the figures when I executed your code. Please help me to correct this. The vertical space consumed is very important to me.

Comment: @Fizzle: As per the image above, when I compile the example, the labels are not below, but on the sides. So, without a complete example that reproduces the problem not sure how I can diagnose the issue you are experiencing.  Putting the code into a `minipage` should not have any effect on the labels positions (except that they not need to fit into a narrower page).

Comment: Thank you Peter. I have been able to detect the problem at my end. The scale I was using was too high hence the problem. Thanks once again!!

Answer (score 5):

I have a slightly different solution:

```
\documentclass[draft]{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htb]
\centering
\hspace*{1.5em}\raisebox{\dimexpr-.5\height-1em}
  {\includegraphics[scale=0.4]{Figures/knockho1.eps}}%
\subfloat[\label{label1}]{\hspace{1.5em}}
\\[\medskipamount]
\hspace*{1.5em}\raisebox{\dimexpr-.5\height-1em}
  {\includegraphics[scale=0.4]{Figures/knockho2.eps}}%
\subfloat[\label{label2}]{\hspace{1.5em}}

\leavevmode\smash{\makebox[0pt]{\hspace{17em}% HORIZONTAL POSITION           
  \rotatebox[origin=l]{90}{\hspace{2em}% VERTICAL POSITION
    Some text that should go at the side}%
}}\hspace{0pt plus 1filll}\null

Some text that should go below

\medskip

\caption{This is the text that describes \protect\subref{label1} and \protect\subref{label2}.}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

You can work on the distances next to `VERTICAL` and `HORIZONTAL` for fixing the position of the rotated label.

Usual caveat: the `demo` option to `graphicx` is just to make the example.
In general, however, it's better to specify the width of the figures, rather than the `scale` factor.

[image]