# How can I have labels on the plots in latex, drawn in R

Tags: graphics

I used R to get different plots. I saved them as pdf. I went to my tex. file and I used `\includegraphics` command. The plot came but it does not have labels on, that is, x-labels, y-labels and title-labels. Please advice.

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/61261/add-a-figure-title-and-x-axis-label-to-a-figure-matrix-created-using-pdfpages and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/87653/how-to-add-a-single-axis-label-to-multiple-graphs ?

Comment: Are the labels visible in the `.pdf` which was saved from R? Try different pdf-viewers on the `.pdf` created by latex and try zooming in and out in case it is "only" a problem of visualisation of the pdf-viewer

Answer (score 1):

Whithout a minimal working example (see [I've just been asked to write a minimal example, what is that?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)) is hard to guess the problem, but a way to overcome this problem and simplify your work is use `Sweave` (or `knitr`). Briefly:

1) First, you can make a `file.Rnw` like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
Some \LaTeX{} text.
\begin{document}
\SweaveOpts{concordance=TRUE}
<<echo=F,fig=T>>=
data(CO2)
attach(CO2)
plot(uptake~conc, xlab="x label", ylab="y label", main="The main label")
@
\end{document}
```

2) Then, compile it with R to obtain a `file.tex`:

```
R CMD Sweave file.Rnw
```

3) Finally, Compile your `file.tex` as usual to obtain `file.pdf`.

For simple files as the above MWE, or a working preview, where just one pdflatex compilation is enough, you can omit the step 3 and use the`--pdf` option in 2:

```
R CMD Sweave --pdf file.Rnw
```